# running jquery validation inside modal and twitterbootstrap wizard?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Hope somebody can help me with this, it's been almost a day now and I still can't figure out how to solve this. Right now I have a button that when click opens a jquery modal dialog, inside the dialog there is a twitterbootstrap wizard that works fine. I can click the next and previous button with no problem, now when I try to implement a jquery validation to it as to the example provided in its documentation it is not working. But if I remove the bootstrap wizard from the dialog and put it in a simple page the validation is working. I don't know if I am missing something or something is wrong with my code. Btw I am doing this in asp.net webform page. Please see below for my codes:

Head Section

```
<link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="prettify.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
```

Body and Jquery Script Section

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">

  <form>
  <fieldset>
    <div id="rootwizard">
                            <div class="navbar">
                                <div class="navbar-inner">
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Login Account Information</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Personal Information</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">List of Available Subjects</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-content">
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="emailfield" runat="server" CssClass="required email"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
                                    2
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
                                    3
                                </div>
                                <ul class="pager wizard">
                                    <li class="previous"><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
                                    <li class="next"><a href="#">Next</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
  </fieldset>
  </form>

</div>
    <asp:Button ID="createuser" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.bootstrap.wizard.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="prettify.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var $validator = $("#form1").validate({
                rules: {
                    emailfield: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true,
                        minlength: 3
                    }
                }
            });

            $('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard({
                onTabClick: function (tab, navigation, index) {
                    return false;
                },
                'onNext': function (tab, navigation, index) {
                    var $valid = $("#form1").valid();
                    if (!$valid) {
                        $validator.focusInvalid();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
            window.prettyPrint && prettyPrint()
        });

        $(function () {
            $("#dialog-form").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 500,
                width: 980,
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                draggable: false
            });

            $("#createuser")
            .button()
            .click(function () {
                $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Initial thoughts...

I see you've got a nested form element - i.e a form placed inside another form. I would change that and try again to see if anything changes.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">

  <form>
```

I suspect this may be the root of the issue as it isn't allowed according to the spec.

> 4.10.3 The form element
>
> Categories Flow content. Contexts in which this element can be used:
>   Where flow content is expected. Content model: Flow content, but with
>   no form element descendants.

[Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/forms.html#the-form-element)

In essence, a call to submit on the inner form will trigger on the outer form - most likely breaking validation, or causing a conflict of some kind.

There's a great topic on the subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms) - where someone even quotes a method found in the WebKit source code which only creates a new `<form>` if it's not directly a child of an existing one.

#### ... Well, kinda.

Having just quickly looked through the examples you've showed me, one thing has jumped out, this is the way the browser is interpreting the mark-up of your form:

```
<form method="post" action="twitterwizardinsidejquerymodaldialog.aspx" id="form1" novalidate="novalidate">
  <div class="aspNetHidden">
    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMTA3MzQyODM5NGRkGJwy+BJArQAbccGL8gkmxzW56BSXmxDbjmF1Bht/VZc=">
  </div>

  <div class="aspNetHidden">
  <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEdAANJ+VG2lcl0hLS1uBTEILjay9ZjNWlmWCE+F+bmmsDR55U8pUpLxmspHusBqybX31fKmP5z3oI1K/0xP04OEpQtSyYfoXmQEPT2tZ+zsIIvWQ==">
 </div>
</form>
```

Somehow the form is getting truncated, meaning that validation *does* pass - as that input field technically isn't present. (Meaning validation is automatically skipped)

If you open up a web inspector (i.e Google Chrome's Developer Tools) and manually drag the appropriate elements in to the form itself - *then validation works perfectly*.

By viewing the source of the page you can see the form element closes exactly where you attempt to open a new form:

```
<form method="post" action="twitterwizardinsidejquerymodaldialog.aspx" id="form1">
  <div class="aspNetHidden">
    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMTA3MzQyODM5NGRkGJwy+BJArQAbccGL8gkmxzW56BSXmxDbjmF1Bht/VZc=" />
  </div>

  <div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEdAANJ+VG2lcl0hLS1uBTEILjay9ZjNWlmWCE+F+bmmsDR55U8pUpLxmspHusBqybX31fKmP5z3oI1K/0xP04OEpQtSyYfoXmQEPT2tZ+zsIIvWQ==" />
  </div>
  <div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">  
<form>
```

### So this means?

It looks pretty clear that the nesting of forms is causing this, and I would try and remove the inner form - without knowing it's purpose it just looks kinda pointless.

If this is the case, then rather than opening a new form element the rendering engine is closing the existing one. This would also explain why placing wizard elsewhere allows it to work.

Comment: #FergusMorrow the dialog-form id will be called when I click the button. If I remove the another form tag inside the div dialog-form, the modal dialog will open for a few seconds and then automatically close.

Comment: Interesting, when you say "its not working" in your original post - what actually happens? Does validation fail or does validation just not occur?

Comment: #FergusMorrow when it is not inside the modal dialog the validation occurs. The next button will stop and display the textboxes with errors. Now when I put the wizard inside the modal dialog the validation will not occur. When I also inspect it with firebug the form tag is missing inside the dialog-form div. Later I'll try to post a jsfiddle for a live demo or paste a link from my page.

Comment: Yeah, a jsfiddle case would be pretty useful. I mean, if firebug isn't seeing an inner form element then it does appear that it's not creating it, possibly due to nesting. But that still doesn't explain everything, and actually - it should still work as you run validation on ```#form1```; the outer form.

Comment: #FergusMorrow please kindly see the ff link:
inside the modal dialog [link](http://mylab.comporg.net/twitterwizardinsidejquerymodaldialog.aspx)
outside the modal dialog [link](http://mylab.comporg.net/twitterwizardoutsidejquerymodaldialog.aspx)

Comment: See updated answer. It is the form nesting that's causing the issue, should be quite easy to fix by simply removing that element from your mark-up. In essence it's breaking the page from being rendered correctly, closing the outer form too early - this then leaves jQuery unable to see any child input elements - so the validation rules are skipped and the wizard continues.

Comment: #FergusMorrow - I think I'll just paste the wizard in a normal page and link it,rather than in a modal dialog. So far all the forums that I know, I have also asked this question but nobody answered it except in this forum.

Also those hidden fields that you have said are all created by ASP.NET by default.